# inserting data into MYSQL tables by using shell script

Tags: mysql, shell, unix, awk

I am a beginner in shell script. I am trying to store the output of a LINUX command in MySQL tables. I need to select the partition details in a column and used `%` in another column. I nearly made it but i get the output  in a single column.In table test, disk is a column and used is another column. My desired output is

```
**DISK**            **USED**

filesystem            45%
```

but my actual output is like

```
**DISK  USED**

filesystem  
45%
```

My code:

```
df -h | tee /home/abcd/test/monitor.text;
details=$(awk '{ print $1 } ' monitor.text);
echo $details;
used=$(awk '{ print $5}' monitor.text);
echo $used;
mysql test<<EOF;
INSERT INTO test_1 (details,used) VALUES ('$details','$used');
EOF
```

Please give me the correct code for the desired output.
 Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean you get two lines in the output because you have two separate `echo` statements? If so, replace them by a single statement (`echo $details $used`). If not, please be more clear what you mean by "output".

Comment: output appears in a single column. no matter what is the output

Comment: What output? The output of `df`? The output of `awk`? The output of the script? The output of a `SELECT` on the database?

Comment: What happens if you replace single quotes with double qoutes in `INSERT`, that is: `INSERT INTO test_1 (details,used) VALUES ("$details","$used")`?

Comment: Ok. What happens if you use `INSERT INTO test_1 (details,used) VALUES ("Filesystem","45%")`?

Comment: that appears as what I need. But the data inside the table is the output of a shell command. If I manually type inserting into table, I get My output, but when it is from passing the variable, output displays in single column. Is that  because I  store it in a variable in my code?

Comment: Good.. It should not be the variable that cause trouble. Try inserting after `echo $used;` the following two lines: `details="Filesystem" ; used="45%";`

Comment: By the way, do you use `bash` shell?

Comment: yes, I use Bash shell

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script which captures the value of those 2 columns fine You can do the inserts?

```
#!/bin/sh
df -h | awk '{ print$1 " "  $5} ' > monitor.txt
exec<monitor.txt
value=0
while read line
  do
     col1=`echo $line | cut -f1 -d " " `
     col2=`echo $line | cut -f2 -d " " `
     echo $col1
     echo $col2 ;
 done
```

Plug your insert statements inside the do-done loop.

Comment: why is the statement exec<$fname
 used for? what should I use in my case instead of fname

Comment: Can some one help me with the exact code what I need.
My requirements:
1. I must able to check the disk usage in command. 
2. I must get the partition details in a column of a table and the equivalent used % in the next column of the table.

Comment: Removed the parameters and made it one script (above). You should be able to take it from here.